# Errors in SFML in CLion on Windows 10

Tags: cmake, sfml, clion

So I'm new to C++ and CMake, and I've been trying for the last couple of hours to include the SFML audio library to my project.

I cloned [the SFML repo](https://github.com/SFML/SFML) and put it in Program Files as shown in the code below.

My project only consists of

1. main.cpp with the default "Hello, World!" message.
2. CMakeLists.txt with:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
   project(SFMLtest)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
   set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
   add_executable(SFMLtest ${SOURCE_FILES})

   set(SFML_ROOT "C:/Program Files (x86)/SFML")
   link_directories("C:/Program Files (x86)/SFML/bin")
   set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake_modules")
   find_package(SFML COMPONENTS system audio REQUIRED)

   if(SFML_FOUND)
       include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
       target_link_libraries(SFMLtest ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
   endif()
   ```
3. cmake_modules/FindSFML.cmake directly copied from the SFML repo.

The error messages I receive are:

```
CMake Error at cmake_modules/FindSFML.cmake:354 (message):
Could NOT find SFML (missing: SFML_SYSTEM_LIBRARY SFML_REQUIRED_LIBRARY)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I cloned the SFML repo and put it in Program Files` - Repository contains **sources**. You need to **build** and **install** SFML for work with it. Follow [instructions](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/compile-with-cmake.php) reffered by the project's readme.

Comment: Please use an OS designed for development, not for gaming, to do the programming. That means Linux or *BSD, or at least Mac OS X.

Comment: While I like CLion, if you're developing on Windows, I'd recommend Visual Studio community edition instead.  The reason folks are recommending that you not clone into Program Files is that Windows has put permissions on Program Files that prevents ordinary users from writing into it (this is a good thing).  Either clone into your Documents folder (IMO this gives you a clumsy long path) or into a directory like `C:\dev` for which you have full permissions.

Comment: @iksemyonov I see no reason to harsh on the guy's programming buzz.  It's perfectly reasonable to develop software on Windows.